# Using Textarea inside of styled components makes it write backwards by resetting position of cursor in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, textarea, styled-components

I am using `Textarea` from `react-textarea-autosize` and `styled` from `styled components`. I am writing a `renderForm` function inside a class which renders a form including a `StyledTextarea`. After analyzing, I have found out that using the Styled, each time I write a character, the positon of the cursor resets in the beginning so it makes it write backwards. 
I have checked using just a simple `<input>`, just a simple `<Textarea>` and all of them works normally. Just when I add the styled component, it behaves like this. The code snippet is given below:

```
class ActionButton extends Component {
    renderForm() {
        const StyledTextarea = 
            styled(Textarea)`
            resize: none;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
          `; 

        return (
            <StyledTextarea
            autoFocus
            onBlur={this.closeForm}
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return renderForm();
    }
}
```

This is my first post in stackoverflow. Please pardon any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the declaration of `StyledTextarea` is causing the problem. If it is declared outside the class, it works fine. I am not sure why though. So the code snippet should look like:

```
const StyledTextarea = 
    styled(Textarea)`
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  `; 

class ActionButton extends Component {
    renderForm() {
        return (
            <StyledTextarea
            autoFocus
            onBlur={this.closeForm}
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return renderForm();
    }
}
```

Of course, if there are dependencies from inside the class/states/props, then you have to make a function and pass the dependencies as parameters.